# Value of global variable: Output of a C++ program

Tags: c++, function, global-variables

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int m=10;

int f(int z(int, int))
{
    return z(10, 10) + m;
}

int x(int a, int b)
{
    m=200;
    return a + b + m;
}

int main()
{
    cout << f(x) << endl << m;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
420
10
```

In the above code, if the value of m is changed to 200 in the function x(), then why does is show to be 10 in the output in the main function ?

Here's the link to the code:
http://ideone.com/qZIDXr

Comment: Because you're assuming the function got called *before* `m` was evaluated in `main`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Beside the point but could you tell me what `int f(int z(int, int))` means? A declaration within an argument list?

Comment: @cad A function parameter declaration. See it working [here](http://ideone.com/ZLo6Yc)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How does that work? Do you have any reference on that handy? I mean, I've never seen a **function declaration** inside an argument list and even if I were familiar with this, where's the definition of `z`?

Comment: @cad Seems to work the same way as using a function pointer. Got no reference at hand now, sorry.

Comment: @cad: There is no definition.  It's syntax-sugar for a function pointer.